# What is the resulting shape all orbitals are added up?

Tags: physical-chemistry, orbitals

In all scientific books and Wikipedia ([e.g. this video](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Atomic_orbitals_and_periodic_table_construction.ogv)), the shapes of s, p, d, and f orbitals are always drawn individually, but not the sum of them.

If we add up all the orbitals of an atom, for example for the atom of krypton, what will be the resulting shape, or what space will be occupied?

Answer (score 8):

If you take a look at all of the electron density of an isolated atom, it must be spherically symmetric over a time average. Why? Because space is isotropic, that is, it looks identical in any direction. Specifically, our choice for $x$-, $y$-, $z$- axes is arbitrary.

If you say that the electron distribution is not symmetric, there must be some preferred direction, call it $z$. But our choice of $z$ is arbitrary in space, so some other $z$ will do just as well, and we expect that the atom will have the same preferred direction, which is a contradiction. The original assumption of non-spherical distribution is wrong.